# System.TypeLoadException: 'Method 'get_SerializationSettings' when using KeyVault from Load Test Plugin

Tags: .net, azure, visual-studio-2017, load-testing, azure-keyvault

I have a load test that uses `Key Vault` to pre-authenticate web requests.
As soon as the code tries to call the method that uses `KeyVaultClient` class inside, the following exception throws:

> System.TypeLoadException: 'Method 'get_SerializationSettings' in type
>   'Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClient' from assembly
>   'Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation.

I have tried to downgrade the KeyVault nuget to the version `2.0.6`, but I receive the same error, with version 2.0.0.0.

I am using .NET framework 4.7.2 and Visual Studio 2017 v.15.9.7

UPDATE: The issue appears when the nuget Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime nuget (referenced by Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault) is updated to version 2.3.20. If I roll it back to v. 2.3.18, the load test works fine.

Comment: Please share the code base you are trying.

Comment: Here is a link: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aiq7mZR1Cdrpwdd7NJkWyTC4DMzagQ

Answer (score 0):

Here is something i used it in my code while accesing keyvault client using 3.0.3 library and it worked for me.
try this below and see if it works.

```
Uri ADL_TOKEN_AUDIENCE = new Uri(urlAudience);
var client = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(GetAccessToken));
```

```
public static async Task<string> GetAccessToken(string azureTenantId, string azureAppId, string azureSecretKey)
{
    var context = new AuthenticationContext(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Authority") + tenantId);
    ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(appId, secretKey);
    var tokenResponse = await context.AcquireTokenAsync(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("VaultUrl"), clientCredential);
    var accessToken = tokenResponse.AccessToken;
    return accessToken;
}
```

Try to get the token in this way, it should work.

Comment: This does not work. The exception appears on entering the method that uses KeyVaultClient class. Seems that it happens during the JIT compilation of some static methods in this class.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the load test uses the app.config from the host process "QTAgent_40.exe":

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\QTAgent_40.exe.config

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.5.0.0-9.0.0.0" newVersion="9.0.0.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```

The Newtonsoft.Json - dll is loaded from the folder "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies" (Version 9.0). 
But Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime 2.3.19 (and higher) requires Newtonsoft.Json 10.0.

Solution:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\QTAgent_40.exe.config

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.5.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```